# Android : Merging audio and video file in android Q

Tags: android, audio, video

I have to merge video with audio. I have used following solution but it give me error.

file formats are *mp4 and *mp3.

Sample code

```
val h264Track = H264TrackImpl(FileDataSourceImpl(videofilepath))
        val aacTrack = AACTrackImpl(FileDataSourceImpl(audiofilepath))

        val movie = Movie()
        movie.addTrack(h264Track)
        movie.addTrack(aacTrack)


        val mp4file: Container = DefaultMp4Builder().build(movie)

        val fc: FileChannel = FileOutputStream(
            File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString().toString() + "/videddo.mp4"
            )
        ).channel
        mp4file.writeContainer(fc)
        fc.close()
```

LogCat

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index=0 out of bounds (limit=0)
    at java.nio.Buffer.checkIndex(Buffer.java:556)
    at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.get(DirectByteBuffer.java:224)
    at com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.H264TrackImpl.readSamples(H264TrackImpl.java:297)
    at com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.H264TrackImpl.parse(H264TrackImpl.java:108)
    at com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.H264TrackImpl.<init>(H264TrackImpl.java:90)
    at com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.H264TrackImpl.<init>(H264TrackImpl.java:96)
    at com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.H264TrackImpl.<init>(H264TrackImpl.java:100)
    at com.rgsoft.common.player.MusicMerging$Companion.mearge(MusicMerging.kt:34)
    at com.rgsoft.common.player.MusicMerging.mearge(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.rgsoft.common.player.Mp4ComposeActivity.lambda$onCreate$11$Mp4ComposeActivity(Mp4ComposeActivity.java:280)
    at com.rgsoft.common.player.-$$Lambda$Mp4ComposeActivity$8T7OML37enfUSPyO-Op24LTUz3g.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7201)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7170)
    at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:806)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27562)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7697)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Comment: What is exactly your question?

Comment: I am getting java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:  error while merging audio and video

Comment: If there is any other solution give me lib name.Thanks

Comment: Which statement causes the exception? Do you understand the exception?